# How do I count the number of consecutive occurrences of a character in a string in Scala?

Tags: string, scala, count, char

Let's say I have the string:

```
"AAAAA BBB CCCC AA"
```

I want a way that I can count the occurrences of consecutive characters to give a string that looks like:

```
"5A 3B 4C 2A"
```

How do I go about this?

Currently, I have tried looping through the string, and for each character, I use a match case, and within each case, I start a new loop to count how many times that character appears consecutively, I then try to replace that substring with the desired substring.

Comment: What have you tried? Why it didn't worked? Which specific problem you have? What are your restrictions, which Scala version, can you use built-in methods, can you use of external libraries? Will always the group of characters be separated by a space? Just one space or many? What should happen if a passed string doesn't follow that format?

Comment: Ok, so the spaces don't really matter, they don't affect the outcome. Spaces or no spaces it doesn't matter. So the problem is that there are certain characters that equate to some calculations. And each time they are called they perform a calculation. So to optimise this method, rather than calculating every time the program reads one of the characters, it will look at the pair, so the number of times that calculation of needs to be executed.

Comment: I at the moment have been trying to loop through and count the number of times a character appears consecutively, and then replace that substring with the new pair.

Comment: However I am struggling to get this to work, and it seems quite inefficient. I thought there may be a better way.

Comment: So actually you would be better with other data structure like **List[(Char, Count)]**. Also, you actually just care about consequent characters, no matter the format. Finally, can you show us in your question what have you tried?

Comment: Ok, yes, there won't actually ever be spaces in the input string.

Answer (score 4):

Build a `List` of `(n:Int, c:Char)` tuples then reformat it to whatever `String` representation you desire.

```
"AAAAABBBCCCCAA".foldRight(List.empty[(Int,Char)]){
  case (c, hd::tl) if c == hd._2 => (hd._1 + 1, c) :: tl
  case (c, lst) => (1,c) :: lst
}.map(tup => s"${tup._1}${tup._2}").mkString(" ")
//res0: String = 5A 3B 4C 2A
```

Answer (score 1):

For this kind of problems, I like to write my own **tail-recursive** algorithm.

```
def countConsecutiveCharacters(str: String): List[(Char, Int)] = {
  @annotation.tailrec
  def loop(remaining: List[Char], currentChar: Char, currentCount: Int,
           acc: List[(Char, Int)]): List[(Char, Int)] =
    remaining match {
      case char :: xs if(char == currentChar) =>
        loop(
          remaining = xs,
          currentChar,
          currentCount + 1,
          acc
        )

      case char :: xs =>
        loop(
          remaining = xs,
          currentChar = char,
          currentCount = 1,
          (currentChar -> currentCount) :: acc
        )

      case Nil =>
       ((currentChar -> currentCount) :: acc).reverse
    }

  str.toList match {
    case char :: list =>
      loop(
        remaining = list,
        currentChar = char,
        currentCount = 1,
        acc = List.empty
      )

    case Nil =>
      List.empty
  }
}
```

You can checkout the code working [here](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/LWkuZBkNSMaz8rHDayqxGA/2).

You may replace all that with one `foldLeft`, but IMHO, this way is cleaner and easier to read.